# Presto View On Union of Two hive tables

Tags: mysql, hadoop, presto

I have two Hive tables department  and department1.

I am tring to create a view in Presto using the two tables

```
presto:roc4_cp6> CREATE View deps1 AS
              -> SELECT dep.dept_id, dep.dept_name
              -> FROM (
              ->   SELECT a.dept_id, a.dept_name  
              ->   FROM department a  
              ->   UNION ALL
              ->   SELECT b.dept_id, b.dept_name 
              ->   from department1 b
              -> ) dep;
```

I am able to create a View but when i try to retrive from the view , i get an exception.

```
presto:roc4_cp6> select * from deps1;
Query 20160920_102714_00049_niuph failed: BoundedExecutor is in a failed state
```

Comment: Looks like a case for the [presto issue tracker](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues) to me. At the very least, you should get a more helpful error message, but I strongly suspect a bug.

Comment: Can you run the CLI with the --debug option and post the stack trace?

Comment: whenever i used to fire this query it was actually stopping my presto server with out of memory exeption. So i did the needed.